# Why use bundled code as entry point in package.json?

Tags: node.js, npm

I've noticed a trend of `package.json` files that have a `main` value pointing to a `dist/` folder, for example:

```
{
  "name": "foo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/foo.js"
}
```

(where `dist/` is usually the output of a build tool such as Webpack)

I usually expect `main` to be the source entry point, something like `src/index.js`.

What's the rationale for using bundled code as an entry point? Doesn't this get complicate dependency management, since another library that consumes `foo` doesn't necessarily know what's been included in `dist/foo.js`? (It could its own dependencies, or it might not.)

Answer (score 0):

it allows you to reference the dist code from another project using git

e.g. in project.json

```
dependencies:{
    "foo": "git+https://example.com/foo-lib#v1.0.0"
}
```

this will get the branch or tag for v1.0.0